# Can the state of a standard C++ iostream manipulator be polled?

Tags: c++, iostream, manipulators

When writing an overload for the iostream << operator, particularly on an application class, it may be desirable to alter the behavior of that overload based on the standard manipulators in effect on that stream object.  Can the state of standard manipulators of a stream be polled from within implementations of << overloads?

For example it might be desirable for

```
std::cout << std::internal << myClassReference;
```

to behave differently than

```
std::cout << std::left << myClassReference;
```

beyond the differences the custom overload of << may be handing off to member <<'s in its implementation.

If the manipulator state of an iostream can be polled, how is this accomplished?  Also what should someone implementing custom manipulators do so that the state of *their* manipulators can likewise be polled?

Comment: see [std::ios_base::flags()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags), which returns a `fmtflags` struct with the formatting information contained therein

Comment: @jaggedSpire make that an answer

Comment: @clcto added the answer, I was looking for a duplicate, but didn't find any immediately obvious ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling a c++ stream for its formatting state can be accomplished with the [flags()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) function of the `std::ios_base` class, from which all c++ streams inherit.

The `flags` function comes in two varieties: a `const` polling function called with `stream.flags()`, and a setting function called with `stream.flags(mynewflags)`. Both of these functions return a copy of the `fmtflags` object in its state before the call to `flags`.

---

Implementing a custom manipulator set would be a bit more difficult, and requires the implementer to first decide how they wish to store and access those manipulators. Personally, I would have a preference for implementing another stream object inheriting from `std::ios_base`, possibly indirectly, and using it to encapsulate both a base stream (probably just one from the standard library, with this new class possibly templated on the stream type) and the additional manipulator flags. Anything else would require either a way of checking for the manipulator flags in an external variable, or remembering to pass the variable in with any printing function, which would put a damper of the use of `operator<<` for output. This mean you would need to make another member function for polling your custom flags, but really that seems wise anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  The ironic thing is that I was already using the flags function to save and restore state but had missed that I could also introspect with it.